# save after copy excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, save

I am getting vaguely defined errors from Excel when I try to save after copying a sheet from 1 workbook to another. This only occurs after the original worksheet has been closed.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Month As String = comboMonth.Text() + "_" + comboYear.Text()
    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("K:\SMT\Metrics\" + Month)
    Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
    Dim dra As IO.FileInfo

    Label1.Text = "Displaying All Files in K:\SMT\Metrics\" + Month + "\"
    For Each dra In diar1
        ListBox1.Items.Add(dra)
    Next


    Dim n As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count 'Counter for loop
    Dim f As String 'name of document for opening and loop progress
    Dim XL As Excel.Application 'just for opening master 
    Dim BK As Excel.Workbook 'just for opening master
    Dim SHT As Excel.Worksheet 'just for opening master
    Dim BK2 As Excel.Workbook 'just for opening spreadsheets
    Dim SHT2 As Excel.Worksheet 'just for opening spreadsheets
    Dim Name As String = comboMonth.Text() + "_" + comboYear.Text()
    Dim Document As String = "K:\SMT\Metrics\" + Name + "\" + Name + "_Metrics.xlsx"
    Dim Location As String = "K:\SMT\Metrics\" + Name
    XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    XL.Visible = True 'Only true for troubleshooting
    XL.UserControl = True 'Only true for troubleshooting
    BK = XL.Workbooks.Add 'New Spreadsheet
    SHT = BK.ActiveSheet
    BK.Sheets("Sheet2").Delete() 'Format
    BK.Sheets("Sheet3").Delete() 'Format
    Dim d = Convert.ToChar(n + 65)

    Do While n > 0
        d = Convert.ToChar(n + 65)
        ListBox1.SetSelected(n - 1, True) 'Highlite last item in list
        f = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() 'save the name of the file
        BK2 = XL.Workbooks.Open("K:\SMT\Metrics\" + Month + "\" + f) 'Open the file highlited
        SHT2 = BK2.ActiveSheet 'focus on opend sheet
        SHT2.Copy(SHT) 'Copy focused sheet into "new" Spreadsheet
        BK2.Close() 'kill
        BK2 = Nothing 'kill
        SHT = BK.ActiveSheet 'Focus on copied sheet
        SHT.Name = f 'renamed focused sheet
        SHT2 = BK.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Dim for the sheet being built The next long bit is the main report being built
        SHT2.Cells(2, 1) = "Components Placed"
        SHT2.Cells(3, 1) = "Good Placements"
        SHT2.Cells(4, 1) = "False Call (Determined good)"
        SHT2.Cells(5, 1) = "Bad Parts/Placements"
        SHT2.Cells(6, 1) = "Pass Rate"
        SHT2.Cells(6, n + 1) = "=(" + d + "3+" + d + "4)/(" + d + "2)"
        'BK.Worksheets("Sheet1").Row(6).NumberFormat = "#.##%"
        SHT2.Cells(1, n + 1) = f
        SHT2.Cells(2, n + 1) = SHT.Cells(9, 44)
        SHT2.Cells(3, n + 1) = SHT.Cells(11, 44)
        SHT2.Cells(4, n + 1) = SHT.Cells(13, 44)
        SHT2.Cells(5, n + 1) = SHT.Cells(15, 44)
        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(n - 1) 'delete list item just process
        ListBox2.Items.Add(f) 'write processed file in done list
        n = ListBox1.Items.Count 'update count 'exit loop at 0
    Loop
    n = ListBox2.Items.Count 'get a good count for determining Math Column
    d = Convert.ToChar(n + 65)
    SHT2.Cells(1, n + 2) = "Total"
    SHT2.Cells(2, n + 2) = "=SUM(B2:" + d + "2)"
    SHT2.Cells(3, n + 2) = "=SUM(B3:" + d + "3)"
    SHT2.Cells(4, n + 2) = "=SUM(B4:" + d + "4)"
    SHT2.Cells(5, n + 2) = "=SUM(B5:" + d + "5)"
    SHT2.Cells(6, n + 2) = "=(" + d + "3+" + d + "4)/(" + d + "2)"

    SHT2 = Nothing
    BK.Sheets("Sheet1").name = Name 'name blank page as the monthly report
    SHT = BK.Sheets(Name) 'Because
    SHT.Activate() 'leave the document on the finished report
    BK.Worksheets(Name).Columns("A:ZZ").EntireColumn.AutoFit()

    XL.Visible = True
    XL.UserControl = True

    'SHT.SaveAs(Document)
    'SHT = Nothing
    'BK = Nothing
    'XL.Quit()
    'XL = Nothing
End Sub
```

Please help me understand what is happening. Also, The code is doing everything I'd like it to do.

Answer (score 0):

As a guide for you, this bit of code will copy SHT2 in a workbook called BK2 which you open, into the currently active workbook after a named sheet(called Data1), and then close the opened workbook BK2.

```
Sub copySheet()
Dim BK2 As Workbook
Dim SHT2 As Worksheet

Set BK2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Data\VBA\SO\Test2.xlsx")
Set SHT2 = BK2.ActiveSheet
SHT2.Copy After:=Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Data1")
BK2.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help. I have added more code above to help clarify. Everything is working except for saving. Also, if I leave all the opened documents open, I can save and then reopen the file without it being corrupt.

Comment: @Vojens - If you are trying to saveas with commented-out line at the bottom of your code, it looks like you are trying to save a Worksheet.  Shouldn't this be BK.SaveAs(Document)?

Comment: Yes, but this problem extends out to me stopping the code and manually saving the document as well... I have been swapping BK and SHT dims as part of my trouble shooting.